# Why is 'to' not used before 'home'?

Tags: prepositions

While learning English, I was taught not to put 'to' in front of 'home'. I.e. "go to home" is incorrect, you should say "go home".

Is there a reason (maybe historical) for this?

Comment: Related: [Prepositions used with “home”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/prepositions-used-with-home).

Comment: I thought it all dated from [URL:"http://www.epicure.demon.co.uk/latinlesson.html"] Romanes Eunt Domus...[/URL] :-)

Comment: Related: [“Playing upstairs” vs “Playing home”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54336/playing-upstairs-vs-playing-home)

Comment: @tchrist - exactly. You did follow the link, right? :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between 'went home' and 'went to home'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111764/difference-between-went-home-and-went-to-home)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this phrase "Go home", **home** is not a noun but an adverb

Specifically, it is an **adverb of place**

So you do not need a preposition like "to" prior to home.

The [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/home_2) specifies

> Do not use a preposition (a word such as 'at' or 'to') before home
>   when it is an adverb

Other [similar adverbs of place](http://www.momswhothink.com/reading/list-of-adverbs.html) are listed below, and you can see you can use the same rule to all of them

> abroad
>   anywhere
>   downstairs
>   here
>   home
>   in
>   nowhere
>   out
>   outside
>   somewhere
>   there
>   underground
>   upstairs

Comment: This looks a little circular. How do I know when *home* is an adverb? In "I am going home", *home* must be an adverb because there is no preposition; in "I work at home", *home* cannot be an adverb because there is a preposition. And knowing this I can decide whether to use a preposition or not.

Comment: @Henry: If you think about it, adverbs of place are describing *where the <verb> happens*. I "I work *at* <place>" home is obviously a noun. So you can have a preposition.

Comment: Contrast "I am going home" and "I work at home" with "I am going upstairs" and "I work upstairs". It seems I have to know these phases in order to know when *home* is an adverb and when a noun, as it is sometimes possible to say "I work <adverb of place>". So the rule "Do not use a preposition (a word such as 'at' or 'to') before home when it is an adverb" is not helpful.

Comment: @Henry I agree with you. Take a look at this: [“Playing upstairs” vs “Playing home”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54336/playing-upstairs-vs-playing-home)

Comment: I’m pretty sure that my home is not an adverb.

Comment: What about *go to school*, then *to school* is adverb again?

Comment: This "rule" seems like a tap dance around an irregularity in the language.  If the language doesn't fit the rule, redefine the language rather than accept that the rule has exceptions.

Answer (score 11):

I've never been happy with the suggestion of adverbial status of nouns that can just as easily be parsed as objects.

i.e. If "home" is where "I am going", then "home" is the object of the verb.  For it to be an adverb, it would have to modify "going", which it doesn't (with "I am going quickly", "quickly" clearly modifies how the "going" is carried out).

The difference between nouns where we use "to" and where we don't is more to do with the non-specific meaning of the object noun.

"Home" is a non-specific place, in this context, in that you cannot put a determiner in front of it without losing its (intrinsic/abstract/personal) meaning:

i.e. none of these work:
-- "I am going the home."
-- "I am going that home."
-- "I am going a home".

For specific places (you can tell they are specific, because you need a determiner to specify which one), the "to" is required.

I don't want to shout down Longmans, because they do an extremely difficult job very well, but sometimes they do drift a little from reality.

Comment: +1 This answer also helped, but I think @JoseK's answer is  more apt. Thank you.

Comment: The adverb *home* does modify the verb: it lets us know the direction of motion.  Some similar adverbial constructions are: *Where* did you go?  I went *away*.  Adverbs have several functions, only one of which describes manner.

Comment: @mark wallace I've said it before, but I'll say it again, all adverbs are are attributes of attributes. In this case, 'I' is in the category of substance, 'go' is in the category of action (an attribute of substance) and 'home' is in the category of where, an attribute of the attribute of going. Aristotle's 10 categories are prior to grammar, which codifies the relationships between them.

Comment: OK I think I understand. In English we write or say, I am going home...not I am going "to" home. It's an exception (present continuous). It's confusing, especially since you can write or say "I am going to school" or "I am going to Church". It's an exception that you just have to learn. Of course, you can always say "I am going to my home".

Comment: Verbs of movement have no object. They are not transitive. You don't ask I'm going + whom/what. You ask I'm going + where to.  Verbs  of movement are a construction class of their own as they are followed by special indications as where to or taking what way (through the woods) or in which direction (this way, north).

Answer (score -2):

I go home. "Home" is an adverb of place that modifies verb "go".

I go to my home. "Home" is a noun, so we use preposition "to"+ noun "home" to complete the meaning.

I am home. Some authors mention "home" in this sentence is a noun. (You can find in dictionary,too). But I think it is not correct. 
"Home" in "I am home" is a noun.
 How can we use an adverb "home" after a liking verb "BE"? Therefore, "home" must be a noun and in this special situation the preposition "At" is dropped. That is why we write 
" I am at my home." (home = noun)
I come home. (home = adverb of place)
I come to my home (home= noun)
I come back to my home> (home = noun. To comeback to = phrasal verb )

Comment: But people say "I'm at home" all the time. The only time I regularly hear people say "I'm home" is when they're calling out to the other people in the house to let them know they've arrived.