# "On the way home" — "to" preposition

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 'to' not used before 'home'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home)

I have noticed that the "**to**" **preposition** is never used when one is heading **home**. some examples:

> I am on the way home 
>   Would you please give me a ride home?

But for other locations, **"to" preposition** is used:

> I am on the way **to** school 
>   Would you please give me a ride **to** school?

Is my understanding correct? If so, why no preposition is used for home?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

The word *home* may be not only a noun, but also an adverb, an adjective and even a verb ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/home)). In your example, *on my way home*, *home* is an adverb meaning the direction, in which someone/something is headed, i.e. towards a location, they call *home*.

*Home* certainly can be used with preposition *towards* (not sure if it can be used with *to*) but usually people tend to omit unnecessary words in speech. Thus *on my way home* is the most common form.