# Difference between 'went home' and 'went to home'

Tags: prepositions

I'm a little bit confused over the difference between the following sentences.

I went home.
I went to home.

Could someone please explain the difference.

Comment: The second one is ungrammatical.

Comment: Why is it ungrammatical ? if I went to park, I went to school are correct, why isn't I went to home correct too ?

Comment: "I went to park" *isn't* grammatical, unless you mean "I went to park the car"

Comment: @PrasadWeera: It is idiom. Normally, use *to* + article. The words *home* and *school* are idiomatic exceptions (there are more).

Comment: And there are different usages: _I went to school_ (ie was part of the school community / went that day to study) vs _I went to the school_ (perhaps to see if the reports about it being an Art Deco masterpiece were true). UK usage is _I went to hospital_ (ie was an inpatient) but _I went to the infirmary_ (either usage).

Answer (score 4):

The peculiar usage of *home* without the preposition 'to' is explained by [paco2004](https://www.englishforums.com/user/ddnh/profile.htm)
at [“Adverbial Objectives?” at “English Forward” (englishforums.com)](https://www.englishforums.com/English/AdverbialObjectives/bvwmv/post.htm):

> Many English nouns and noun phrases can be used as adverbs. They are
> called "adverbial objectives". From the standpoint of word order, an
> adverbial objective is put as if it were an objective of a verb, but
> actually it works as an adverbial modifier of the verb. This sort of
> construct comes from an Old English grammar rule that allowed the use
> accusative cases of nouns as adverbs. For example, let's take an Old
> English sentence "He eode ham"[=He went home]. From the view of
> current English the word "ham" [home] would be treated as an adverb
> but it was the accusative of the noun "ham" in Old English.

The noun "ham" in Old English corresponds to 'to {his} home' rather than just '{his} home' in present-day English: i.e., the *to* is considered to be “built into” the *home* where required; this is possibly the only word this occurs with nowadays.

Other directional adverbial objectives / other adverbials not taking 'to' (there aren't many) include:

He's gone some place. (colloquial)

He's gone somewhere.

When did you come here?

When will you go there?

Comment: The linked thread (EF) is gibberish. Adverbial objectives??