# Why can we say "is your mother home?" but we can't say ''is the boss office?"

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Why can we say "Is your mother home?" but we can't say "is the boss office?"
originally Why to ask if someone is at home? you can say "is your mother home?", but you can't say "is the boss office" to ask if someone is in the office.

Comment: For the same reason we can't "walk office" or "go office" or "hit office". But maybe in 100 years people will be saying that.   Grammar describes how people use the language, it doesn't set the rules; and people don't use "office" in that way.

Comment: This is answered by John Lawler in ['Home' in 'Ben and Jen went home.' Can an adverb be a noun at the same time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/111426/191178), though I'm not sure it's close enough to actually close this as a duplicate.

Comment: More simply, one of the definitions of "home" is that it's equivalent to "at home". There's no analogous definition for most other place names.

Comment: You can say though "**Is the boss in?**”

Comment: You can say "Is the boss home?" :p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prepositions used with "Home"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3807/prepositions-used-with-home) Saying 'it's an adverb, not a noun, in this usage' or 'it's better analysed as an intransitive preposition' get no nearer to answering _why_ 'home' behaves this way. [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111764/difference-between-went-home-and-went-to-home) explains why 'He went home' has no preposition ['to' in this case], and probably 'at home' was likewise expressed by a single word in earlier days.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Adverbs don't normally function as complement of "be", so an adverbial classification makes no sense. Modern grammar rightly classifies it as a prep, meaning "in/at one's usual place of residence".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course the prep analysis explains it. *Go* takes a preposition phrase as a complement. You can have *to* or *home* or *away*, but not *to* and another preposition. *_Go to away_ , for example.

Comment: @Araucaria You're missing the point. Analysing 'home' as a preposition is one way of reconciling things (if you're prepared to make concessions along the line). But **why** does 'home' behave this way when say 'office' doesn't?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's like saying *Why does* fly *have a past tense when* frog *doesn't?* The answer is because *fly* (the *fly* that has a past tense) is a verb, and frog is a noun! *Home* behaves like that because it's a prep and *office* doesn't because it's a noun! The verb *go* takes PP complements, not NP ones!

Comment: @Araucaria Essentially, with examples where one might expect 'to home' at least, the dative form of the noun 'home' (now deceased as a separate entity), which included the prepositional element, has coalesced with the prototypical noun. This explains the 'why', at least for the directional usage. What one _calls_ the covert dative etc is arguable.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *"Is your mother home?*"
>
> [2] *"*Is the boss office?*"

Traditional grammar classifies the "home" in [1] as an adverb. But adverbs don't normally function as complement of "be". Modern grammar sensibly classifies it as a preposition, meaning "in/at their usual place of residence".

In [2] "office" is a noun, but it doesn't have a locational meaning like "home", and so makes no sense as complement of "is". Instead, the prepositional "in his/her office" is required.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111764/difference-between-went-home-and-went-to-home

Comment: @Greybeard Frankly, the content in that linked site (EF) is absurd. For example, it's ridiculous to say that "Many English nouns and noun phrases can be used as adverbs". Anyone with even a modest knowledge of English grammar would find that laughable.

Comment: It is then ironic that, to the intended audience, it is perfectly understandable. On the other hand, what I assume is Pullam and Huddleston's idea that "home" is a preposition is really risible and shows a deep ignorance of the origins of "home" the adverb/adjective.

Comment: @Greybeard Don't be ridiculous. As far as modern grammar is concerned, the origins are irrelevant. I explained to you in my earlier comment the grammatical reason that it can't be an adverb. Even this humble dictionary gets it right:  [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/home)

Comment: *As far as modern grammar is concerned, the origins are irrelevant.* Not in this case: Old English is why we have this syntax.

Comment: @Greybeard Modern grammar looks at the evidence. You should try it some time.  I've explained to you that adverbs don't normally function as complement of "be", so an adverbial classification makes no sense. Together with its meaning of something like "in one's usual place of residence", everything points to it being a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

**Home** is a

> **Noun** I. The place where a person or animal dwells. (OED)

and

> **Adverb** 1.e. Without verb of motion. Arrived at one's house, neighbourhood, or country after a period of absence. Also: in one's
> home; at home. (OED)

**Office** is only a noun. There is no adverb "office".

Comment: I think the OED is wrong about "home". Adverbs don't normally function as complement of "be", so an adverbial classification makes no sense. Modern grammar classifies it as a prep, See my answer.

Comment: This answer is erratically.