# "At home" or "home"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What is the rule of not using *at* before *home*?
For example,

- When he called me I was (at) home.
- I am always (at) home on Sundays.
- He came to my place at 6pm and by that time I had already been (at)    home.
- Hello! Is anyone (at) home?
- I am (at) home at last!
- I am always complimented (at) home.

Comment: Updating my browsers didn't help. Now I have to update Windows. I will accept all the answers as soon as I can.

Comment: Post a question in [meta] and report the problem (acceptance checkmark not visible), along with OS version numbers and browser names and versions.

Comment: Question [Prepositions used with home](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3807) partly duplicates your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't researched this, but it seems to me that *at* is

- optional when *home* is the complement of a form of *be* (*am*, *was*, *are*, *been* etc)
- required when *home* is a modifier (as in your last example)
- disallowed with *go*, *come* and synonyms.

But I'm sure there are some exceptions to these rules of thumb. One interesting one is your third example:

> He came to my place at 6pm and by that time I had already been (at) home.

where *at* changes the meaning. *Had already been home* invokes the idiomatic meaning of *been* as a sort of verb of motion, and implies that I had been home and gone away again.

*Had already been at home* is barely possible for me without an expression of duration (*Had already been at home for several minutes*).

Comment: +1 for without an expression of duration (Ok, for all of it) For me it is not possible without a duration. Absent a duration it would just be "I was [already home | already at home]"