# Using "at" with "home"

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

Why don't we use *at* when we use *home*? For example:

> I arrived home
>   *vs.*
>   I arrived *at* home

or

> I am home
>   *vs.*
>   I am *at* home

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope. 
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: The premise of this question as it is asked is somewhat faulty, because [we do use "At" with home sometimes](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+at+home%2C+I+am+at+work&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20at%20home%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20at%20work%3B%2Cc0). However, we don't use any prepositions with a verb's direct object, as exemplified in the first sentence. Now that you mention it though, I suppose I am curious why we can substitute "I'm home" for "I am at home" when we can't omit the preposition for any other location.

Comment: @Tonepoet Can you find a dictionary licensing 'arrive' as a transitive verb? Not everything that looks like S + V + DO actually _is_.

Comment: The question is a duplicate of [“At home” or “home”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69958/at-home-or-home). Though Gary brings out further detail in his answer here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Although I can](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/arrive), that obsolecent sense doesn't apply here so, I admit that I made a bad presumption in this case. I'd state my next assumption in normal conversation, but I'd rather not make the same mistake twice given the circumstances. v_v

Comment: The prepositionless locative/directional usages of 'home' have been covered before. Essentially, they stem from old declension, single words meaning at-home / to-home. These became isomorphic with the noun, and nowadays their POS is contentious. Adverb of place / intransitive preposition (I still don't like either, and stick with locative or directional particle).

Comment: @Tonepoet ~ my bad: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Scq3i.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both, they both mean the same thing, literally.

In common usage they are used slightly differently.

If I have just arrived home, I would say "I am home".

Whereas if someone asked me where I was, I would say "I am at home".

Idiomatically you would not use the word arrive often as a native English speaker, you would instead say "I came home". There's a little discussion about this [here](http://josecarilloforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=326.0).