# Is the verb "Go" always followed by "to" when talking about a place/location?

Tags: prepositions, particles

Other than the phrase

> Go home.

I can't find other uses of *go* without *to* when talking about a specific destination/physical place.

> I am going to California.
>
> She went to Milan.

The other uses of *go* (*go crazy*, *go shopping*, and so on) shouldn't be taken into consideration here.

Comment: Not when I'm going *from* California.

Comment: @HotLicks that wouldn't be expressing a destination

Comment: No, but it does express a physical place.  And you can also go *toward* California.

Comment: And you can go somewhere, go West, go upstairs, go visit Milan etc.

Comment: @MrLister somewhere isn't specific.

Comment: @HotLicks I've edited the question

Comment: Addressed at [Why is this sentence wrong? ... He went to home](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233564/why-is-this-sentence-wrong-he-went-to-home/233598#233598). 'Go/come home' is an exception; note that _come_ normally requires _to_ also.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see, adverbial objectives could be used to express location/destination without the need for `to`. That'll do !

Comment: No. *I'm going **into** California.* *She went **into** Milan.*

Comment: Yes @Clare , we've established to to express the action of going somewhere, you can use others prepositions, adverbial objectives, or other constructs mentioned by Mr.Lister

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Erm, probably not actually. *Home*, although it looks like its homohponouns noun counterpart is a preposition (or adverb if one really must). So *come home* and *go home* both have the preposition phrase *home* as a locative Adjunct.

Comment: So which adverbial objectives other than _home_ specify specific destinations?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is that last comment addressed to me?

Comment: @Araucaria Erm, if one subscribes to the CGEL treatment. There are real problems with their super-lumping to include intransitive prepositions. 'Arriving early at the ferry docked at the roadside, we drove on.' / 'Home' in this usage is a relict of an inflected form of the noun and if anything is a prepositional phrase that has lost its preposition. 'Locative/directional particle' is as far as I'm prepared to go.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth some were listed by Mr Lister: go West/East, go upstairs, ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But *home* being analysed as an adverb is not very new or controversial. (Actually neither is intransitive prepositions. It's been mainstram for about 50 years, it's nothing special to H&P). [I don't get what point is being made in the example given, btw]

Comment: No, west and east are directions not termini in 'go west'. 'The West', maybe, but then you'd need 'journey to the West'. Arguably, upstairs isn't totally specific as a destination either (one floor up or ten?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Touché, you're right. Currently the `NSLinguisticTagger`in iOS can only categorize words being verbs/nouns/prepositions. So my workaround is this: lemmatize the sentence, look for `go`, then see if it's followed by a preposition. Dropping the preposition (if any) from the rest of the sentence gives us the destination

Comment: @Araucaria The analysis as intransitive preposition derives ultimately from obviously related parallel structures. 'He is in the/his house' and 'He is in'. But with 'Arriving early at the ferry docked at the roadside, we drove on.' it is not clear whether 'on' is a shortened form of 'onto the ferry' or not.

Comment: "OK, I've arrived at the house.  What should I do next?" "Go in."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *GO* can be used with many  prepositions, including the preposition *home* and the preposition *to*. When the verb *GO* indicates to travel, it usually takes a Locative Complement. This is usually in the form of a preposition phrase. The preposition phrase may consist just of an intransitive preposition (these are regarded by some traditional grammars as 'adverbs'), or it many consist of a preposition phrase taking another preposition phrase as Complement. It it may, of course, consist of a preposition taking a noun phrase as Complement:

- He went north. (*intransitive preposition*)
- He went out of the building. (*preposition with preposition phrase complement*)
- He went into the shed. (*preposition with noun phrase complement*)

**The Original Poster's question**

The Original Poster asks if the verb *GO* is always followed by the preposition *to* when the sentence mentions a specific location or destination. The answer is NO! Here are some examples:

- He went inside the cinema.
- He went aboard the ship.
- He went into the maze.

Comment: So there would always be prepositions between the verb `go` and the destination?

Comment: @Carpsen90 Not exactly, because sometimes the preposition itself indicates the destination, so there may be no need for an extra, intervening preposition. Consider *go home*, *go abroad*, *go away*, *go inside*, *go outside*, *go upstairs* etc, etc. But if the destination is represented by a *noun phrase*, then yes, you do need an intervening preposition!

Comment: For a computer to understand that we're talking about a destination, the sentence should either have this form: `go`, preposition, noun phrase; or `go`+ locative complement or adverbial objectives?

Comment: @Carpsen90 Well, a Locative Complement could be either: prep; prep + prep phrase; prep + noun. However, I think it'll be difficult to isolate all the genuine prep + noun locative adjuncts from other idiomatic uses of *GO*. Consider for example *go on a bender*, *go round the bend* and so on.

Comment: @Carpsen90 So, to give an indication of the problem *go round the bend* could either be an idiom meaning *go crazy* or it could involve a Locative Complement. The only way of telling is from the context ...

Comment: Yes I understand that part. What am trying to solve is parse a sentence entered by a user in natural language. and location could be expressed by many constructs, like: "*Have a pizza with Jane at Freddy's*"

Comment: Extracting the location expressed in a sentence, using different constructs, in different languages, is a wider problem that I'll have to deal with. Thank you for your input, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** There are other propositions besides *to*, which can be used in conjunction with the main verb *go*, when specifying a place or destination. For example,

- to go near the US Border wall
- to go around a lake
- to go between two trees

Comment: I see, other particles could be used, but not without at least one, like "go home"

Comment: @MrLister I've just seen your modified comment. Yes you're right

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking if *to go* needs to be followed by a preposition to indicate the targeted location, and I say ‘Yes, I think so’ because a place is localized, ideally to a point, whereas *going* is a transition between points. An official explanation would probably relate to transitivity [1].

Putting *to* in front of the identifier of the destination implies a path. *To go home* is likely not an exception, because *home* is also a verb (as in *homing missile*), whereas *to go [verb]* is common. Although, *to go to ask stackexchange* does not seem grammatically wrong to me. I'd suspect the infinitive has been dropped in favor of clear distinction between this construction used with places or activities. To prefer losing the infinitive seems to be an affinity of the English language, as evidenced by a clear preference for the gerund for example.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivity

Comment: The reason behind the exceptional behaviour of 'home' is explained in the relevant thread.