# Go + to + noun phrase

Tags: noun-phrases

Does the construct "Go + to + noun phrase" always express going somewhere, a specific physical location?

For example:

- *Go to school*
- *Go to the movies*
- *Go to the nearest store*
- *They went to Paris*
- *We will go to my aunt's*
- *G̶o̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶a̶c̶k̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶l̶i̶n̶e̶*

Not taking into account expressions like *go to hell* and noun phrases that can't be looked up in a map.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are an interesting discussion there about the meaning of adding *the*. This question is rather closer to [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375587/is-the-verb-go-always-followed-by-to-when-talking-about-a-place-location) one.

Comment: But Neil Coffey answers this question in the thread linked to above.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth adding the derminant *the* or not, either way, an actual place is implied. An app that parses natural language could look up actual places in sentences having this construct.

Comment: Should 'Go to the back of the line' be included as a relevant case or not? You seem to include it, it's directional/deictic, but you can't find it on a map. Your question is unclear. // 'Go to work' has various senses, one of which is merely 'start work' (cf 'Go to it!'). As stated in Neil's answer, 'go to school' obviously has an association with one (or more) geographical locations, but is usually used for 'attend [a] school', where the location is backgrounded and almost out of sight.

Comment: I hear "Go to your happy place" to mean relax, so that's an abstract destination.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you're right about *go to the back of the line*, it should be used as a counterexample. I totally agree and understand Neil's answer to that question, but that's not what I'm asking. And like you said, even when omitting the determinant, the *association with one (or more) geographical locations* still lingers in the back thought. One could assume in an app the school/hospital/restaurant implied by analysing the nearest/most frequented places by the user or recommending new ones.

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes that would be a counterexample

Comment: Go to a meeting, go to the meeting, go to church, go to the doctor, go to a better place, go to get my hair done, go to my appointment, go to the phone, go to the door, go to the bathroom.  Locational, not necessarily geographic.

Comment: @Xanne most of the couterexamples you've provided are valid, *get my hair done* isn't a noun phrase

Comment: @Carpsen90 I understand about "get my hair done."  But add: go to confession, go to therapy.  It seems to me "go to the back of the line" is more locational--a "somewhere" identifiable in the context of the event.  But the answer to your basic question seems to be "No."  That doesn't mean you can't write a "go to" app; It just means it won't cover every use of "go to" + noun phrase.

Comment: @Xanne I agree, it's not a definitive way of expressing the act of going somewhere.

Comment: You can "go to work" even if you work from home. It just expresses the metaphoric change from personal activity to business activity.