# Why do we use "to" for "go to sleep", but do not use it for "go home"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Why we say "go to sleep" and don't say "go sleep"?
Why we say "go home" and don't say "go to home"?

Comment: *Home* is an adverb; *sleep* is functioning as a noun (or a verb; but not an adverb). See [a closely related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/158141/usage-of-go-to-vs-go)

Comment: Note that we **do** say "go to [one's] house."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this sentence wrong? "He went to home."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233564/why-is-this-sentence-wrong-he-went-to-home)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

we use the noun house use "to".

Answer (score 1):

In a sentence as "Go home" the word **home** functions as an adverb  modifying verb **go** and it implies sort of sense :  **at or to your house or the place where you live**

Please check [cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/home) and [this question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33762/the-nuance-of-using-the-word-home-as-an-adverb-noun-with-or-without-prepositio)

Comment: In this case "at or to your house or the place where you live" we must use |"to home", don't?

Comment: What difference  between "go home" and "go my home"? Why in first one  "home" is adverb and in second one "home" is a noun?

Comment: because in first is anywhere

Comment: @Mohsen Mirzaei Farrokhshahi , words are mostly classified according to their functions in a sentence.  Home functions as an adverb of place just like "there", "here".  In a sentence like  "go to house", house is a noun referring to "a building". So we use a preposition to create "adverbial phrase" so that we can modify verb.

Comment: In "go home", also "home"  referring to "a building",  what's the difference?

Comment: @Mohsen Mirzaei Farrokhshahi  home may sound a bit  abstract It refers to "where someone lives"  not "building" itself. it might be a country, a city, a village -  a "place" you live in

Comment: In this case"My father wants to know when you are coming home." , home means house, not a country , a city , a village , why don't it use "to home"?

Comment: @Mohsen Mirzaei Farrokhshahi Home is not a "building".  If  intended meaning is "building" you need to use "house" not  "home"

Comment: ecuse me Mustafa, go to school , why isn't school an adverb? school is place for education. that is mind such as "home" and we must say "go school". another question is : in that sentence where place "home" refer to?

Comment: @Mohsen Mirzaei Farrokhshahi  ,  vocabulary is created arbitrarily by native users of  a language, so we do not have a right to ask why this word is adverb or other is noun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65079/discussion-between-mohsen-mirzaei-farrokhshahi-and-mustafa).